# strcmp in c ( invalid conversion)

Tags: arrays, c, string

Here is problem from codeforces https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A

And this is my code which I'm stuck.

```
char full_string[100];
char string[100][1];
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(full_string); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        if (j = 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(string[i][j], string[i + 1][j]) < 0)
            {
                char temp;
                temp = string[i][j];
                string[i][j] = string[i + 1][j];
                string[i + 1][j] = temp;
            }
        }
        printf("%c", string[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Complier told me this one.

"  Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'  "

The main problem is at strcmp.It said it expected const char* but string argument is char.
Should I create a new array of int which store the number. Then I'll use atoi which will convert string to integer. So I can use "if(expression)" instead of strcmp.

Comment: You're passing a  `char` variable, but arguments of `strcmp()` must be `(char*, char*)`

Comment: Where you write `char string[100][1];`, what are you expecting `string` to look like in memory - what do you expect to the the dimensions? When you then do `string[i][j]`, are you expecting to get a pointer out of that, or a single character? If a pointer, why? if a single character, why do you expect it to work with `strcmp` like that?

Comment: the posted code is nothing but a code fragment.  It is missing the needed `#include` statements.  It is missing a 'main()` function (it fact it has no function definition at all)   Please post a [mcve] so we can simply copy your code, to reproduce the problem

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(full_string); i++)`  the returned type from `strlen()` is `size_t` (an unsigned long int) and this statement is trying to compare that unsigned value with an `int` which is a signed value

Comment: regarding: `if (j = 0)`  this is an assignment, NOT a comparison.  I suspect you meant a comparison: `if (j == 0)`  Notice the `==`

Comment: regarding: `if (strcmp(string[i][j], string[i + 1][j]) < 0)`   Since the array: `string[]` has not been set to any known value, this is comparing what ever trash is on the stack at the location of `string[]`  This is an error

Comment: regarding: `char string[100][1];`  this is declaring an array of 100 rows, where each row is 1 element long.  Therefore, `for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)` is trying to access beyond the length/end of each row (the only valid index into each row is 0, because in C, an array index starts with 0, not 1

Comment: regarding: `printf("%c", string[i][j]);`  what are you expecting this to print, when `j` is greater than 0?

Comment: regarding: `for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        if (j = 0)` since `j` is always being assigned to 0, the result is an infinite loop

Comment: *memory limit per test 256 megabytes* bloat has won, beyond all reason. How sad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here is the prototype of `strcmp` function:*

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

It compares two strings and returns 0 if the compared strings are equal. A non-zero value if string1 is bigger or smaller than string2.

If you want to compare two characters you must use a normale compare just as you do to compare `int`.

**For example:**

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
if (a == b) {
   printf("%c is equal to %c\n", a, b);
} else {
   printf("%c is not equal to %c\n", a, b);
}
```

In this case obviously a != b

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need `strcmp` since you're trying to just compare two characters as limserhane's answer mentioned above.

```
if (strcmp(string[i][j], string[i + 1][j]))
```

should look like

```
if (string[i][j] < string[i + 1][j])
```

Plus, I can't understand what you're trying to do, as following code

```
char temp;
temp = string[i][j];
string[i][j] = string[i + 1][j];
string[i + 1][j] = temp;
```

would switch the locations of a number and a '+' operator.

Since the problem is considering students are handling single digit number, I would write a helper function that gets all the single digit numbers as character array/string, then sort, and then return it back all sorted.
Then just add '+' operator wherever it needs.

Comment: Furthermore, the purpose of `for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)` is unclear, even after fixing the `if (j = 0)` as `if (j == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs a bubble sort on the passed in char array

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
void swap( char *xp, char *yp) 
{ 
    char temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 
  
// A function to implement bubble sort 
void bubbleSort(char arr[], size_t numelements) 
{ 

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numelements-1; i++)       
    {
       // Last i elements are already in place    
       for ( size_t j = 0; j < numelements-i-1; j++)  
       {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
            {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I leave it to the OP to extract the data digits (I.E. drop all the `+` symbols.

I leave it to the OP to print out the results

Answer (score 0):

The code has multiple problems:

- you pass single `char` values to `strcmp` instead of pointers to `char`: this is incorrect and will cause undefined behavior. Just use `if (full_string[i - 2] > full_string[i]) { /* swap characters */ }`
- there is no need for a 2D array `char string[100][1];` just sort `full_string` in place.
- compute the length of `full_string` just once at the beginning of the outer loop.
- bubble sort should be fast enough so sort 50 entries in less than 2 seconds.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *sort_summands(char *str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    int sorted = 0;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < len; i++) {
            if (str[i - 2] > str[i]) {
                char c = str[i - 2];
                str[i - 2] = str[i];
                str[i] = c;
                sorted = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char buf[128];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        fputs(sort_summands(buf), stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```